# iPhone 11 and iPad stopped inserting a period after double tapping space bar

Tags: iphone

This started when phone updated to  IOS 13 
It slows me down ... I have to shift to add the period

I have down a hard shutdown, reboot, checked all my settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit this setting in „General“ -> „Keyboards“ -> “.“ Shortcut.